# Как имитировать выбор файла с компьютера (в input type file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileupload, windows-server

Есть сайт, на котором есть поле выбора файла:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Я хочу автоматизировать процесс, чтобы браузер сам без участия человека мог выбрать нужный файл на компьютере, вставил его в `input type="file"` и нажал на кнопку отправки формы.

Так как я узнал что браузер сам не может выбрать файл с компьютера, может быть тогда можно как-то в `input type="file"` подставить файл который предварительно будет загружен на мой сервер?

Или может быть можно как-то отправить POST в котором как-то передать файл (который будет предварительно загружен на мой сервер, и иметь прямую ссылку, типа `https://site.my/file.csv`

Следует отметить что сайт `input type="file"` не принадлежит мне (то есть доступа к его коду я не имею, чтобы там что-то настроить, все что имеем это форму для загрузки файла).

Знаю что такое решение точно как-то можно реализовать, может быть средствами какой-то программы для Windows...

Буду очень благодарен за полезную информацию!

Comment: Можете попробовать selenium для этого.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а можно подробнее? Может есть какая-то статья?

Comment: На счет статьи не уверен, но информации в интернете много https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128208/how-to-deal-with-file-uploading-in-test-automation-using-selenium-or-webdriver/6129464#6129464

Comment: А это обязательно делать через браузер?